# How to switch from one to another tab using jQuery,java script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

How to switch from one to another tab using jQuery,java script???

Comment: Take your time and forumlate the question properly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean "switch among browser tabs", I think that it is not possible nor advisable: browsers do not allow to take control over them without the intervention of the user.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are using jQueryUI tabs plugin. From the demo page:

```
$('#example').tabs('select', 2); // switch to third tab
```

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#...select_a_tab_from_a_text_link_instead_of_clicking_a_tab_itself